# rust futures-cpupool: inconsistent behavior explanations

Tags: concurrency, rust, threadpool, future

I'm experiencing weird behavior with [cpu pools](https://docs.rs/futures-cpupool/0.1.2/futures_cpupool/):

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate lazy_static;
extern crate tokio_core;
extern crate futures;
extern crate futures_cpupool;

use std::time::Duration;

use futures_cpupool::{CpuPool, Builder, CpuFuture};
use futures::Stream;
use futures::{Future, future, lazy};
use futures::sync::mpsc;
use futures::Sink;

lazy_static! {
    static ref CPU_POOL: CpuPool = {
        Builder::new()
        .pool_size(10)
        .after_start(|| {
            println!("Pool started one thread");
        })
        .before_stop(|| {
            println!("Pool stopped one thread");
        })
        .create()
    };
    }

struct Producer {}

impl Producer {
    fn search_names(&self) -> Box<Stream<Item = String, Error = String> + Send> {
        let (mut tx, rx) = mpsc::channel::<Result<String, String>>(1);

        println!("Creating producer thread...");
        let producer_cpu: CpuFuture<(), ()> = CPU_POOL.spawn(lazy(move || {
                println!(" -- Begin to produce names");
                for i in 0..10 {
                    match tx.send(Ok("name".to_string())).wait() {
                        Ok(t) => {
                            println!(" -- sent the name");
                            tx = t
                        }
                        Err(err) => {
                            println!(" -- Error occured sending name! {:?}", err);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    std::thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
                }
                future::ok::<(), ()>(())
            })
            .then(|result| {
                match result {
                    Ok(data) => println!("Producer finished with data: {:?}", data),
                    Err(err) => println!("Producer finished with error: {:?}", err),
                }
                future::ok::<(), ()>(())
            }));

        rx.then(|r| r.unwrap()).boxed()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let producer = Producer {};

    let names = CPU_POOL.spawn(producer.search_names()
        .map(|name| {
            println!("name = {:?}", name);
            name
        })
        .collect()
        .then(|result| {
            match result {
                Ok(data) => println!("Finished to read producer {:?}", data),
                Err(err) => println!("Error reading stream of producer! {:?}", err),
            }
            future::ok::<(), ()>(())
        }));

    names.wait();
}
```

Here is the corresponding Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "example"
version = "0.1.0"

[dependencies]
lazy_static = "^0.1.*"

tokio-core = "^0.1"
futures = "^0.1"
futures-cpupool = "^0.1"
```

I'm running on Rust nightly (`1.16.0-nightly (df8debf6d 2017-01-25)`)

I would expect this program to generate the 10 `String`s, output it via `println` and exit. However, most of the time, the program doesn't generate the `String`s and exits normally, other times the `String`s are correctly generated.

Here is the output of the first case:

```
Creating producer thread...
Pool started one thread
Finished to read producer []
Pool started one thread
Pool started one thread
Pool started one thread
Pool started one thread
```

And the output when `String`s get generated

```
Pool started one thread
Pool started one thread
Pool started one thread
Pool started one thread
Creating producer thread...
 -- Begin to produce names
 -- sent the name
name = "name"
Pool started one thread
 -- sent the name
name = "name"
Producer finished with data: ()
Finished to read producer ["name", "name"]
```

I got the feeling that, for the first case, the producer thread doesn't get scheduled on the thread pool for whatever reason. I must be missing something but I don't know what.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the problem is the early drop of the producer future.

On the method `search_names`, the `CpuFuture` that produces value is dropped when `search_names` returns. When dropped, a `CpuFuture` is cancelled, thus skipping production of the values.
The difference in behavior certainly comes from a race between the drop of the future and it's execution.

A solution is to reference the producer future all along the application like this:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate lazy_static;
extern crate tokio_core;
extern crate futures;
extern crate futures_cpupool;

use std::time::Duration;

use futures_cpupool::{CpuPool, Builder, CpuFuture};
use futures::Stream;
use futures::{Future, future, lazy};
use futures::sync::mpsc;
use futures::Sink;

lazy_static! {
static ref CPU_POOL: CpuPool = {
    Builder::new()
    .pool_size(5)
    .after_start(|| {
        println!("Pool started one thread");
    })
    .before_stop(|| {
        println!("Pool stopped one thread");
    })
    .create()
};
}

struct Producer {}

impl Producer {
    fn search_names(&self) -> (CpuFuture<(), ()>, Box<Stream<Item = String, Error = String> + Send>) {
        let (mut tx, rx) = mpsc::channel::<Result<String, String>>(1);

        println!("Creating producer thread...");
        let producer_cpu: CpuFuture<(), ()> = CPU_POOL.spawn(
            lazy(move || {
                println!(" -- Begin to produce names");
                for i in 0..2 {
                    match tx.send(Ok("name".to_string())).wait() {
                        Ok(t) => {
                            println!(" -- sent the name");
                            tx = t
                        },
                        Err(err) => {
                            println!(" -- Error occured sending name! {:?}", err);
                            break
                        },
                    }
                    std::thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
                }
                future::ok::<(), ()>(())
            }).then(|result| {
                match result {
                    Ok(data) => println!("Producer finished with data: {:?}", data),
                    Err(err) => println!("Producer finished with error: {:?}", err),
                }
                future::ok::<(), ()>(())
            })
        );

        (
            producer_cpu,
            rx.then(|r| r.unwrap()).boxed()
        )
    }
}

fn main() {
    let producer = Producer {};

    let (future, stream) = producer.search_names();
    let names = CPU_POOL.spawn(
        stream
            .map(|name| {
                println!("name = {:?}", name);
                name
            })
            .collect()
            .then(|result| {
                match result {
                    Ok(data) => println!("Finished to read producer {:?}", data),
                    Err(err) => println!("Error reading stream of producer! {:?}", err)
                }
                future::ok::<(), ()>(())
            })
    );

    names.wait();
}
```

Comment: This would be why the compiler was telling you *warning: unused variable: `producer_cpu`*